# jQuery is not inserted by PrimeFaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have the following JSF page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>

    <h1>Example</h1>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputText value="Counter: " />
            <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterBean.count}" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="Count" actionListener="#{counterBean.increment}" update="txt_count"/>
    </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

When it loads it doesn't include jQuery on the page (CSS file as well).

Is there any special configuration to force PrimeFaces to include jQuery and CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare the `<h:head>`.

```
<html ...>
    <h:head>
        ...
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        ...
    </h:body>
</html>
```

CSS/JS resources are auto-included through the `<h:head>`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this at the top of your page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    <!-- content goes here -->
    </h:body>
</html>
```

you need to remove this line: primefaces already includes this for you.

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>
```

Comment: sorry, I've not added full page, everything you mentioned is already on the page.

Comment: you're adding the jquery library. that is already included with primefaces xml namespace.  Remove the <h:outputScript> tag and it should work.

Comment: are you serving the page through a JSF servlet container ?

Comment: correct, through Faces Servlet,  url - http://localhost:8080/jsfspring/pages/default.jsf

Comment: do you have the primefaces library jar included in your /WEB-INF/lib folder ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17888/discussion-between-shevchik-and-deefactorial)